# CVS or SVN Modules

Tags: svn, module, cvs

In CVS how can I get the list ONLY the modules that are in a particular branch? Iam looking for the same answer with SVN also. Your answer will be really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by `modules`? In CVS there several possible meanings, whereas SVN does not have them at all (at least not under this name).

Comment: What is the problem you're attempting to solve? There may be a more appropriate way to do it than the method you've already formulated in your mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a branch"? In SVN, ALL the files are in a branch. SVN tracks the state of EVERY file at EVERY revision. Are you looking for files that changed during the life of a branch?